# Lebesgue Decomposition Notation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem I am using is: Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and let $\nu$ be finite positive measure.  Then, there exist positive measures $\lambda$ and $\rho$ such that:

1. $\nu = \lambda + \rho$
2. $\lambda \perp \mu$
3. $\rho \ll \mu$

This makes sense to me.  An exercise I'm given uses a slightly different notation, and I'm not really sure how to interpret it.  It says that the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ can be written:
\begin{align}
d\nu = d\lambda + f d\mu  &  &(1)
\end{align}
This is confusing to me, as I have learned that, given $\eta$ $\sigma$-finite, $\nu$ finite, and $\nu \ll \mu$:

\begin{align}
d\nu &= f d\mu & &\Leftrightarrow & \nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{A} & &(2)
\end{align}

How do I reconcile this notion of the Radon-Nikodym derivative in (2) with the expression in (1)?  The expression in (1) seems sort of nonsensical to me (what does $d \lambda$ even mean here?), so clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Since integrals often are written $\int f \, d\mu,$ it is common to write for example $d\nu = d\lambda + f \, d\mu$ for $\nu(A) = \lambda(A) + \int_A f \, d\mu.$ The symbolic foundation for this is
$$\int_A d\nu = \nu(A) = \lambda(A) + \int_A f \, d\mu = \int_A d\lambda + \int_A f \, d\mu = \int_A (d\lambda + f \, d\mu).$$
Remove $\int_A$ and you get $d\nu = d\lambda + f \, d\mu.$